# unable to edit data in table using PHP form

Tags: php, mysql, forms

Please look into this code unable to find out the actual error:

This is PHP upload code:

```
<?php
            include_once("config.php");
            if(isset($_GET['pro_id']))
            {
            $id=$_GET['pro_id'];
            if(isset($_POST['submitBtn']))          {
            $dept_id = $_POST['dept_id'];
            $cat_id = $_POST['cat_id'];
            /*$pro_id = $_POST['pro_id'];*/
            $pro_name = $_POST['pro_name'];
            $pro_desc = $_POST['pro_desc'];
            $pro_spec = $_POST['pro_spec'];
            $pro_price = $_POST['pro_price'];
            $status = 'on';
            $pro_keywords = $_POST['pro_keywords'];
            //image names
            $pro_image = $_FILES['pro_image']['name'];
            //temp images names
            $temp_image = $_FILES['pro_image']['tmp_name'];

            if($dept_id=='' OR $cat_id=='' OR $pro_name=='' OR $pro_desc=='' OR $pro_spec=='' OR $pro_price=='' OR  $pro_image=='' OR $pro_keywords=='')
                    {
            echo "<script>alert('All the fields are mandatory')</script>";
            exit();
                    }
            else
            {
            //upload image to folder
            move_uploaded_file($temp_image,"images/product_images/$pro_image");
            $run_query1 = mysqli_query($login, "update products1 SET (dept_id,cat_id,pro_name,pro_desc,pro_spec,pro_price,pro_image,status,date,pro_keywords) values (  '$dept_id','$cat_id','$pro_name','$pro_desc','$pro_spec','$pro_price','$pro_image','$status','NOW()','$pro_keywords' WHERE pro_id='$id'");

            if($run_query1)
                    {
                echo "<script>alert('Product updated successfully')</script>";
                exit();     
                    }
            else
                {
                echo "<script>alert('Errors')</script>";
                }
            }           }

            $query1 = mysqli_query($login, "select * from products1 where pro_id='$id'");
            $query2 = mysqli_fetch_array($query1);
            ?>
```

This the form Part where data retrieve from table and when click on the update button nothing happened and page is redirected to view data page and showing the old data:

```
<form action="ViewProduct.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="form1" id="form1">
            <table width="650" border="0">

            <tr>
                <td width="183" align="right">Department:</td>
                <th width="231" align="left">
                <select name="dept_id" id="dept_id">
                    <option>Select Department</option>
                 <?php
                $result=dept_show();

                while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
                {
                    echo "<option value='{$row['dept_id']}'>{$row['dept_name']}</option>";
                }                    
                ?>
                </select></th></tr>
              <tr>
                <td width="183" align="right">Catagory</td>
                <th width="231" align="left">
                <select name="cat_id" id="cat_id">
                    <option>Select Catagory</option>
                <?php
                $result1=cat_show();

                while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1))
                {
                    echo "<option value='{$row['cat_id']}'>{$row['cat_name']}</option>";
                }                    
                ?>
                </select></th></tr>
              <tr>
                <!--<td width="231"><input type="hidden" name="pro_id" id="pro_id" value="<t?php echo $pro_id; ?>" /></td>-->
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td align="right">Product Name/Model:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="pro_name" id="pro_name" value="<?php echo $query2['pro_name']; ?>" /></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td align="right">Product Description:</td>
                <td><textarea type="textarea" name="pro_desc" id="pro_desc" cols="45" rows="5"><?php echo $query2['pro_desc']; ?></textarea></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td align="right">Products Specification:</td>
                <td><textarea type="textarea" name="pro_spec" id="pro_spec" cols="45" rows="5"><?php echo $query2['pro_spec']; ?></textarea></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td align="right">Product Price:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="pro_price" id="pro_price" value="<?php echo $query2['pro_price']; ?>" /></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td align="right">Product Image:</td>
                <td><input type="file" name="pro_image" id="pro_image" value="<?php echo $query2['pro_image']; ?>" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td><input size="45" type="text" name="text" id="text" value="<?php echo $query2['pro_image']; ?>" /></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td align="right">Keywords:</td>
                <td><input size="45" type="text" name="pro_keywords" id="pro_keywords" value="<?php echo $query2['pro_keywords']; ?>" /></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" name="submitBtn" id="submit" value="Update" /></td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </form>
            </div> <?php } ?>
        </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Form method is POST and you are using GET method in if loop

```
if(isset($_GET['pro_id']))
```

Use POST here.

I have made the changes in you complete code. Use this code and if required made the changes (if issues arrived)

PHP code

```
<?php
        include_once("config.php");

        if(isset($_POST['submitBtn']))          
        {
        $dept_id = $_POST['dept_id'];
        $cat_id = $_POST['cat_id'];
        $pro_id = $_POST['pro_id'];*/
        $pro_name = $_POST['pro_name'];
        $pro_desc = $_POST['pro_desc'];
        $pro_spec = $_POST['pro_spec'];
        $pro_price = $_POST['pro_price'];
        $status = 'on';
        $pro_keywords = $_POST['pro_keywords'];
        //image names
        $pro_image = $_FILES['pro_image']['name'];
        //temp images names
        $temp_image = $_FILES['pro_image']['tmp_name'];

        if($dept_id=='' OR $cat_id=='' OR $pro_name=='' OR $pro_desc=='' OR $pro_spec=='' OR $pro_price=='' OR  $pro_image=='' OR $pro_keywords=='')
                {
        echo "<script>alert('All the fields are mandatory')</script>";
        exit();
                }
        else
        {
        //upload image to folder
        move_uploaded_file($temp_image,"images/product_images/$pro_image");
        $run_query1 = mysqli_query($login, "update products1 SET (dept_id,cat_id,pro_name,pro_desc,pro_spec,pro_price,pro_image,status,date,pro_keywords) values (  '$dept_id','$cat_id','$pro_name','$pro_desc','$pro_spec','$pro_price','$pro_image','$status','NOW()','$pro_keywords' WHERE pro_id='$id'");

        if($run_query1)
                {
            echo "<script>alert('Product updated successfully')</script>";
            exit();     
                }
        else
            {
            echo "<script>alert('Errors')</script>";
            }
        }     
    }

        $query2 = array();
        if(isset($_GET['pro_id']))
        {
            $id=$_GET['pro_id'];
            $query1 = mysqli_query($login, "select * from products1 where pro_id='$id'");
            $query2 = mysqli_fetch_array($query1);
        }            
        ?>
```

HTML Code

```
<form action="ViewProduct.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="form1" id="form1">
        <table width="650" border="0">

        <tr>
            <td width="183" align="right">Department:</td>
            <th width="231" align="left">
            <select name="dept_id" id="dept_id">
                <option>Select Department</option>
             <?php
            $result=dept_show();

            while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
            {
                echo "<option value='{$row['dept_id']}'>{$row['dept_name']}</option>";
            }                    
            ?>
            </select></th></tr>
          <tr>
            <td width="183" align="right">Catagory</td>
            <th width="231" align="left">
            <select name="cat_id" id="cat_id">
                <option>Select Catagory</option>
            <?php
            $result1=cat_show();

            while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1))
            {
                echo "<option value='{$row['cat_id']}'>{$row['cat_name']}</option>";
            }                    
            ?>
            </select></th></tr>
          <tr>
            <td width="231"><input type="hidden" name="pro_id" id="pro_id" value="<t?php echo $pro_id; ?>" /></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td align="right">Product Name/Model:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="pro_name" id="pro_name" value="<?php echo $query2['pro_name']; ?>" /></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td align="right">Product Description:</td>
            <td><textarea type="textarea" name="pro_desc" id="pro_desc" cols="45" rows="5"><?php echo $query2['pro_desc']; ?></textarea></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td align="right">Products Specification:</td>
            <td><textarea type="textarea" name="pro_spec" id="pro_spec" cols="45" rows="5"><?php echo $query2['pro_spec']; ?></textarea></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td align="right">Product Price:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="pro_price" id="pro_price" value="<?php echo $query2['pro_price']; ?>" /></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td align="right">Product Image:</td>
            <td><input type="file" name="pro_image" id="pro_image" value="<?php echo $query2['pro_image']; ?>" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td><input size="45" type="text" name="text" id="text" value="<?php echo $query2['pro_image']; ?>" /></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td align="right">Keywords:</td>
            <td><input size="45" type="text" name="pro_keywords" id="pro_keywords" value="<?php echo $query2['pro_keywords']; ?>" /></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" name="submitBtn" id="submit" value="Update" /></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </form>
        </div> <?php } ?>
    </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: how to take this $_GET, i have to 1st retrieve data from the table

Comment: Code you wrote is incomplete. prod_id is commented in form. Its hidden field. Uncomment that filed and store the value in it whenever form load. Check that value when form submit. If value exists then update the data on that prod id else not exists then make the new entry in table

Comment: As per your suggestion, uncommented the pro_id hidden field in the form but getting the same issue, please help

Comment: set the value of prod_id if the form opened for the edit or update

Comment: Santosh, its not working, can you rectify the error and post it so that i can clearly understand the error since i am new in php and i have to submit my project to my institute and one more thing i am using the same code in edit the user details and there is working fine. please help.thank you

Answer (score 1):

Your pro_id field is commented out in your HTML using `<!--` and `-->`, so the following never is true:

`if(isset($_GET['pro_id']))`

Also, you have a mismatch between your form method POST and $_GET that you are looking for.

Comment: Peter, unable to understand, please explain.

Answer (score 1):

Your query of update is correct? I think you must use

```
UPDATE products1 SET dept_id='$dept_id',cat_id ='$cat_id'... the rest of values
WHERE pro_id='$id'
```

And verify if your dept_id is INT as well cat_id, so if they are INT you don't need ''

```
UPDATE products1 SET dept_id=$dept_id,cat_id =$cat_id
```

Comment: dept_id, cat_id & pro_id are the INT datatype, and i have also updated the query but the result is same even the same code is working fine in my another edit page for edit user section, please help

Comment: if they are INT you don't need '$dept_id' just try without '' like $dept_id in every INT column

Answer (score 0):

Try to do this steps:

First thing comment out this line,

```
<!--<td width="231"><input type="hidden" name="pro_id" id="pro_id" value="<t?php echo $pro_id; ?>" /></td>-->
```

next step,
you are sending data using POST i.e. (form method="post"), so use this

```
if(isset($_POST['pro_id'])) , then comment out $pro_id = $_POST['pro_id'];
```

you will get $pro_id value.

Comment: After your suggestion done all the changes but this time not showing the form using if(isset($_POST['pro_id'])), please help.

Comment: <!--<td width="231"><input type="hidden" name="pro_id" id="pro_id" value="<t?php echo $pro_id; ?>" /></td>-->   --- (comment out this line from html file form and make little correction in value field there is <t?php tag which is wrongly type ..type <?php ).  and then in php code instead of  if(isset($_GET['pro_id']))
            {

Comment: i think you are placing if(isset($_POST['pro_id'])) . i think you are placing this in html file..dont put this in html , you have to put this in php code. you already placed if(isset($_GET['pro_id']))  , just change $_GET to $_POST and comment out $pro_id = $_POST['pro_id']; , it will surely work